# Where can i find an Ad Fizz Build?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Builds and strategy guides for champions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19374/builds-and-strategy-guides-for-champions)

Ok so i watched Voyboy play a bruiser Fizz and he said it worked well. TRy as i might i can find a build that is up to date and can only find one ad Fizz build. Anyone got any ideas how to build? like runes masteries and items plus what to level when?

Answer (score 0):

http://solomid.net/guides.php?g=20992

Comment: Please summarise the link here, so that if it goes dead your answer won't be lost.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this guide](http://www.solomid.net/guides.php?g=10468)

This one is specifically for AD Fizz =).  I have played him mid before because I love AP.  He is even worse than facing talon,  at level 2 with full ad runes Fizz totally eats any squishy AD with ignite.

Comment: Could you summarise the contents of the article you linked to, in case it goes away?

Answer (score 0):

You can find builds for champions of all variety on most League of Legends dedicated websites.

For instance:

- [clgaming](http://clgaming.net/guide/champions)
- [solomid](http://solomid.net/guides.php)
- [mobafire](http://www.mobafire.com/)

They mostly have a search and vote systems which can guide you to your desired build.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.lolpro.com/guides/fizz/322-fizz-guide-top-lane

In this guide, Elements made the AP-Fizz part (for top lane still!!) and voyboy did the ad-bruiser fizz part of the guide, so you basicly learn from the master!